# Making a pdfLaTeX document monospaced

Tags: fonts

I have just switched to writing in LaTeX from markdown. I like to proofread by hand, and so in the past I used a template that increased the line spacing and changed the typeface to something monospaced just for proofreading. Now I cannot figure out how to change an entire document to being monospaced.

I found several solutions that seem to only work on LuaLaTeX, but I would prefer to use pdfLaTeX.

Comment: The key terms are `ttfont` and `typewriter` and `monospace`. For example, look here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70758/entire-document-typed-in-monospace-font

Comment: Using memoir class is just add the `ms` option ([example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95793/11604)) to change even the chapters and secton titles.